# Can't set value to edittext

Tags: android, android-edittext

I have a fragment which contains edittext.Edittext filed by data from server.
When this fragment create first time, the edittext filed correct. Then if i click back and start this fragment again the value is disappeared, 
although the data from server received correctly.

Comment: can you show your code here ..

Comment: i think your problem is ..you do every operation inside oncreateview() ..and when you press back and then go to same page..oncreateview can't loads..and data disappear..